# Restore points disappear after dual booting

Tags: windows, windows-8

The restore points, at the new windows OS, disappeared after dual booting to the older Windows OS on the other disk driver.

I reached (while working in the old operation system) to the MountedDevices following the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/974754/167207) of SamBrightman and I cleared the line that says `\DosDevices\D:` (D is the other disk driver with the newer windows),as I didn't fully understand how to disable it, and the restore points are still vanishing.

BTW, the volume shadow copy is running.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "Following the answer..." -- I'm not convinced. What you described here ("I cleared ...") is not following the answer. The answer says "setting the registry key", not "clearing".

Comment: Yes,i know,but when i reached to the MountedDevices(  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices),the next thing that i have is only a screen with several lines. Each line has the names of the drivers(with binary codes),like:\DosDevices\D:(with the binary code).I don't see the line with the words"...\Offline REG_DWORD..."as was shown at the other answer and I can't find any option to disable it.So,i just cleared it.Any ideas how can i disable it in my case?

Comment: Here are a few possible solutions (in case you haven't tried them yet): `https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/system-restore-points-disappear/0bc8dc98-d349-42ad-9fdf-8ab280ac031b`

Comment: @Brian 18,i read the link,but the problem there is difference.The restore point other there disappeared within an hour and he doesn't have dual booting.In my case the restore point is disappeared only when i am booting to the other old driver and return again(dual booting)to the new driver with the new windows(where the restore points vanished).

Comment: I interpret the linked answer as follows: get to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices\Offline` folder in the registry; *if it doesn't exist, create it*. Inside it the key named `\DosDevices\D:` (substitute the right letter) has to be of the type `REG_DWORD` and its value should be `1`. *If it doesn't exist, create it*. This is not an answer because I don't even use Windows. I don't use Windows, still I believe this is how you set a registry key. Clearing it (or something else) is absolutely not setting it.

Comment: Question needs to be edited to state actual problem (restore points disappear after *dual booting*). This should be clear without having to refer to a different post. As it is post lacks vital details / information. I'm voting close.

Comment: @joep van Steen,i was needed only clarification to a certain part in the answer(for the original question)that i couldn't figure it out.The question was old,so i had to open a new question as a continue to it.It is not a new question.But i edit it anyway.

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski,i was going to create(expand)as you adviced,an \OFFLINE folder after the \MountedDevices,so it will be:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices\Offline,but i don't see any option to add a folder of  the Offline folder.How should i create one?

Comment: The only Windows I can access now is a virtual XP. There in `regedit` I can right-click `MountedDevices` in the tree and choose "new -> key" (or something like that, my XP is not in English) to create `Offline`. Then I can right-click `Offline` and choose "new -> DWORD".

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski.Thanks to your very helpful information and guidance the problem was solved,As you realized exactly what was the source of the issue.Thanks.

Comment: In regards to the question itself,i suggest not to close it,since the very helpful comments of Kamil Maciorowski are very important to understand/clarify the process of the instruction of the original answer(the attached link)and it may help alot for other members that won't fully understand the instruction in the original answer.Thanks.

Comment: @xchcui this question is irrelevant when it comes to that answer. If you feel that needs correction, a comment should be added there. Or an edit should be made, but it should keep author's intent in tact.

Comment: @Destroy666.Will it be more appropriate to change the title to:"how to disable mounting of the newer windows OS disk/partition from the older OS by setting the registry key(dual-booting)?"or it is too late since an answer from Brian had already made?

Answer (score 0):

Restore Points will disappear over time as you make changes to you system based on the space you have allocated. Try increasing allocated space.

[image]

---

Comment: I had already saved 20GB for it,but even if there is only 1 restore point,it vanished as soon as i boot to the older windows version(as it was described in the other question).Unfortunately, the space is not the issue in this case,which could be an easy repair.

Comment: @xchcui - Your question makes no mention of dual booting two versions of Windows

Comment: @xchcui, you should edit your question and add fact you're dual booting and restore points disappear after booting different OS.

Comment: I had already mentioned that it is a continue to another question(i attached a link),it is not a different question.The original question mentions the dual-booting with two windows OS.But okay i will mention it again in my question.